# Session context with gwt request factory

Tags: java, session, gwt, rpc, requestfactory

I have a login method in a GWT RPC Servlet, which gets a user from the session context and therefore determins, if the user is logged in or not. I want to port this method to the request factory approach (to get a proxy entity instead of a DTO).

But where can i place it? I can't place it in the Entity because there i don't have the session context. Whats the right approach here?

My RPC method currently looks like this:

```
@Override
public UserDTO isLoggedIn() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    HttpSession session = getThreadLocalRequest().getSession();

    String userName = (String)session.getAttribute("userName");

    if(userName !=null){
        return new UserDTO(userName);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

RequestFactory also provides methods for accessing the request and servlet context

```
HttpSession session = com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet.getThreadLocalRequest().getSession();
```

Documentation can be found here:

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/server/RequestFactoryServlet.html#getThreadLocalRequest()

Comment: Yes, but i am not accessing that servlet directly from the client side. I just interact with the proxy entities and they don't know about the servlet.

Comment: Exactly, @jan - this is server code. In RPC you write a servlet, but reuse the same DTOs both client and server, but in RF you have entities on the server and proxies on the client. On the server (the only place session is available) you can call the method listed above. There is no session data that the client can understand, as all session lives on the server.

Comment: I am aware of that, but i am not really sure how to integrate a method in the request factory workflow

Comment: There is no difference between `RF` and `RPC` here. 
The same way you pass back your UserDTO object in your RPC call you can do it in your `RF` service method.
You can use the [ServiceLocator](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory#locators) pattern to implement it.

Comment: I don't get it - how can i access the session in the ServiceLocator then?